# vertically center link in li tag that is 11.11% height of parent ul

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I have a menu sliding in from the left. I gave this menu a height of 100vh. I put a ul with some li (menu items) inside each taking up 11.11% of the height (there are 9 menu items).

Now I also have sub menu's sliding in from the left upon hovering on those menu items mentioned above. the sub menus consist of a div with a ul and li's inside it. That div is positioned absolutely with the main ul (mentioned above) positioned relatively (so that each submenu appears in the same place) kind of like this example shown here:

https://www.thecodingguys.net/demo/css/css-vertical-menu-multiple-levels.html

problem is I have links inside the submenus and I am not able to center them vertically. The difference is that the div containing the submenu is 80% of the main ul (outer menu) and the the inner li's are also 11.11% of the ul's height (also 9 submenu items). I tried setting li's to position: relative and the a tags to position: absolute with top: 0, bottom: 0, and margin: auto, 0 but that's not working. here are the css of sub menu:

```
.menu-sub-categories {



    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block !important;
    height: 87%;
    z-index: -1;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 23%;
    background: grey;
    @include prefix(transition, left 200ms ease-in);

    ul {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        height: 11.11%;
        //border: 2px solid red;



        a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid green;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 17px;
            position: relative;                 

            .text-wrap {    
                box-sizing: border-box;
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: auto;
                    width: auto;
                    top: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    margin: auto 0;


            }

            &:hover {
                color: #000;
                cursor: pointer;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }




    }





    }



}
```

here is the full site if you would like to see it:

http://pilot-mule-43300.bitballoon.com/

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this on your `<span>` tag inside the `<a>`

```
span {
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```